# G force roundabout question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

If I'm driving and I want clear a roundabout as fast as possible, but I only can take so much G force before dying, do I drive in the inner or outer lane. Assuming that the maximum G force I can take is constant.

Comment: Your tires will start skidding well before your car reaches unsurvivable g-forces.   (Until your car skids off the road and hits a tree, that is.)

Comment: +1 because this is a really interesting question, and the answer is *not* obvious !

Comment: I agree @gandalf61, I do not understand why this question has been closed?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question (and an interesting one at that) and not a "do my homework for me" question.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume that the entrance and exit to the roundabout are at radius $R$, and you go round the roundabout at a constant radius $r \le R$ and a constant speed $v$. We will also assume that your path round the roundabout is a straight radial line from radius $R$ to radius $r$, an arc of a circle through a turn of $\theta$ radians at constant radius $r$, and finally a straight line from radius $r$ to radius $R$.

The force exerted on your body while travelling around the arc in the middle of your path will be

$\displaystyle F = m \frac {v^2} {r}$

and the time taken to travel through an angle $\theta$ radians about the centre of the roundabout will be

$\displaystyle t_0 = \frac {r \theta}{v}$

The time taken to travel the straight line parts of your path will be

$\displaystyle t_1 = 2 \frac {R-r} v$

So the total time taken to travel around the roundabout will be

$\displaystyle t = t_0+t_1 = \frac {(\theta - 2)r + 2R} v = ((\theta - 2)r + 2R) \sqrt \frac m {Fr} = \sqrt {\frac m F} \left((\theta-2) r ^ {\frac 1 2} + 2R r ^{-\frac 1 2} \right)$

If $m$ and $\theta$ are constant and we set $F$ to its maximum survivable value $F_{max}$ then we have

$\displaystyle t = \sqrt \frac m {F_{max}} \left((\theta-2) r ^ {\frac 1 2} + 2R r ^{-\frac 1 2} \right)$

(Sanity check: if $r=R$ then this reduces to $t = \theta \sqrt {\frac {mR} {F_{max}}}$ so $\omega_{max} = \frac {\theta} t = \sqrt {\frac {F_{max}} {mR}}$ as expected)

Now we split into two cases:

1. If $\theta \le 2$ then both $(\theta -2)r^{\frac 1 2}$ and $2Rr^{-\frac 1 2}$ have a negative (or zero) gradient for all $r>0$, so to minimise $t$ you should maximise $r$ i.e. go round the roundabout in as wide a circle as you can.
2. If $\theta > 2$ then $(\theta -2)r^{\frac 1 2} + 2Rr^{-\frac 1 2}$ has a minimum value at $r_{opt} = \frac {2R} {\theta-2}$, and this is the optimum radius to minimise $t$. However, note that the condition $r_{opt} < R$ is only satisfied if $\theta \ge 4$ radians i.e. if you are going more than about two-thirds of the way round the roundabout..

Comment: There's going to be some pretty deadly g-forces when instantaneously going from the radial path to the arcing path...

Comment: It's important to note that the results here depend crucially on the choice to start at the outer radius and travel straight radially inward, which isn't all that realistic. You're free to make that choice since the question didn't specify what radius we start at or what path we take to change radius, but making a different assumption there would lead to a different answer. (In particular, that's why Toffomat's answer disagrees since it assumes we just start at whatever radius we're circling at.)

Answer (score 4):

There are some strange assumptions in your post, but let's consider the basic question: When going around a circle, and the (centripetal) force is limited, is it faster to take a smaller or a larger radius?

Assume the force is limited to be $F_\text{max}$ (which is presumably limitied by friction on your tyres rather than by you dying or even becoming unconscious), velocity is $v$ and radius is $r$. Then we have$$F_\text{max}=\frac{mv^2}{r}\,,$$
so $$v=\sqrt{\frac{rF_\text{max}}{m}\,}\,,$$so larger radius means larger possible velocity. On the other hand, larger radius menas longer path, and the time for a full circle is$$T=\frac{2\pi r}{v}=2\pi \sqrt{m}\,\sqrt{\frac{r}{F_\text{max}}}\,.$$
Thus, larger radius means longer time in the end. Hence, the inner lane is better.

Note that this assumes that you can accurately choose the maximum velocity (since going too fast likely means crashing), and that there are no other obstacles (e.g,. cars) in the roundabout.

Answer (score 0):

As a hand-waving addition to the more detailed solutions given:

There is more than one useful version of the centripetal force equation. So
$$F_C=\frac{mv^2}{r}={m\omega^2}{r}$$where:

- $F_C$ is the centripetal force needed$;
- $m$ is the mass of the circling object;
- $v$ is the linear velocity of the circling object;
- $r$ is the radius of the circular path;
- $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the circling object

For a given centripetal force and fraction$^*$ of a complete circle, short circular travel time means high $\omega$ means low $r$.

$^*$My experience as a North American negotiating English roundabouts is that each encounter involves an arc of at least $2\pi \text{ radians.}$  $4\pi \text{ radians}$ or even $6\pi \text{ radians}$ are sometimes required...

Answer (score -1):

According to classical physics, assuming the lanes in the roundabout are parts of a circle, then the G-force can be calculated as without considering other forces:
$$F_g=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$
where $v$ is velocity, $m$ is mass, and $r$ is the radius of the circular path. As you can see in the equation, assuming your mass and velocity are constant, when the radius $r$ decreases, the G-force ($F_g$) increases. This implies that smaller radii produce more force. Thus, it would be best to use the outer lane to clear the roundabout quickly without applying so much G-force.